# Arabic characters in emails are getting decoded (Django)

Tags: python, django, email, python-3.x, django-forms

I used this [code](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/) to help me send emails from the linux server, everything is working fine except that if there was an Arabic character all of the email will be something like this: 2YrYs9mK2KfYq9i62KfZhNix2LPZig==

Note that I use python 3.

P.S.: in the code I added `.encode('utf-8')` in line 46 because I used to get this error **'str' does not support the buffer interface**

---

**UPDATE:**

here's the data that I send using the email function

```
theemail = EmailMessage(subject, message , sender_email, recipients, headers = {
                        'Reply-To': sender_email, 'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                        'From':'sales@e3lani.me', 'Return-Path':sender+' <'+sender_email+'>',
                        'Organization':sender, 'MIME-Version':'1.0', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'8bit',
                        'X-Priority':'3', 'X-Originating-IP':request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'),
                        'X-Mailer':'Python/3.4', 'Message-ID':make_msgid(), 'Date':datetime.datetime.now().time()})

theemail.content_subtype = "html" # though I'm still seeing the <br/> tag as a string instead of giving me a new line LOL
theemail.send()
```

Comment: well, `.encode` is used to convert string to bytes, so if you had used it to do the opposite you are in trouble. Please, readhttp://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html nefore you harm yourself further.

Comment: but this answerr might have mroe into it than simply properly encoding the characters - it looks like a problem of properly marking the charset in the headers and adding the boy according to the convention. Non ASCII chars in hte headers (like "Subject" line or "from" and "to" lines) have to get different markups to signalize their encoding. You have to post your code, and the actual garbage you are getting (characters before the transform and after the transform (not just 'like this' - the actual result is needed)

Comment: @jsbueno I added the problem that I used to get before add the .encode to the code if it helps

Comment: If the message content is "يسياثغالرسي" then the 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' header seems to be the problem. It should be 'base64' instead of '8bit' for anything which is not ASCII and will be encoded in UTF8 and base64.

Comment: @BlackJack I tried that too but it didn't work, I found the solution thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, my problem was with the line I edited in the snippet code I used to sending emails

You see in the original code there was `ps.stdin.write(email_message.message().as_string())` and I added `.encode('utf-8')` to turn the output to bytes! to **solve** the problem I added `.as_bytes()` instead of `.as_string()`

I searched for the reason and I found out that in Python3 `bytes` can be decoded to `str`, and `str` can be encoded to `bytes`, but the opposite is not!